# Problemas al llamar a una función con Java Spring

Tags: oracle, funciones, spring, eclipse, jpa

Me estoy peleando por llamar a una función de Oracle llamada DESENCRIPTAR_NOMBRE desde Java.

El repositorio es:

```
    @Repository
public interface PasajerosRepository extends JpaRepository<Pasajero, Long> {
    
    @Procedure("DESENCRIPTAR_NOMBRE")
    String explicitlyNamedDesencriptarNombre(long key);      
}
```

El objeto Pasajero:

```
@Table(name = "PASAJEROS", schema = "OBP")
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Pasajero implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "KEY")
    private Long key;

}
```

Y tras probar diversas maneras de invocación de la función, me da continuamente el siguiente fallo:

```
Hibernate: 
    {call DESENCRIPTAR_NOMBRE(?,?)}
2022-07-13 14:08:03.830  WARN [il-boarding,74e626c25870e914,abb9a8755d9e25af] 15304 --- [tp1612894697-40] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 6550, SQLState: 65000
2022-07-13 14:08:03.836 ERROR [il-boarding,74e626c25870e914,abb9a8755d9e25af] 15304 --- [tp1612894697-40] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-06550: línea 1, columna 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'DESENCRIPTAR_NOMBRE' must be declared
ORA-06550: línea 1, columna 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

¿A qué se podría deber este error? Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: No parece que exista ninguna función `DESENCRIPTAR_NOMBRE` en tu base de datos.